# Remove String Labels from every Row

Tags: python, regex, csv, pandas, data-cleaning

I am using pandas to read in a csv column where every row has the following format:

`IP: XXX:XX:XX:XXX`

To get rid of the `IP:` prefix, I am editing the column after the fact:

`logs['ip'] = logs['ip'].str[4:]`

Is there a way to perform this operation within `read_csv`, maybe with regex, to avoid the post-computation?

**Update** |
Consider this scenario where there are multiple columns that have these prefixes – is there a better way?

`logs['mac'] = logs['mac'].str[5:]
logs['id'] = logs['id'].str[4:]
logs['lan'] = logs['lan'].str[5:]
logs['ip'] = logs['ip'].str[4:]`

Comment: I don't think so, IMO I think this is the best way as it's vectorised and should be fast

Comment: Can you give the example of what is there and what you want to search using regex ?

Comment: @apgp88 I updated the question with a more specific scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `converters` option for `read_csv` might provide a useful way.  Let's say the file looks like this:

```
id       address
 1  IP:123.1.1.1
 2  IP:456.1.1.1
 3  IP:789.1.1.1
```

Then you could specify that `'IP:'` should be converted to `''` (blank) like this:

```
dct = { 'address': lambda x: x.replace('IP:','') }

df = pd.read_csv( 'foo.txt', delimiter=' *', converters=dct )

   id    address
0   1  123.1.1.1
1   2  456.1.1.1
2   3  789.1.1.1
```

I'm ignoring the slight complication that if there is a space after `IP:` then you might be reading `IP:` in as it's own column, but you ought to be able to adapt this fairly easily to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

you could just convert the csv column to a string the use .split("IP: ")[1] on the string which will contain everything except for "IP: ". I'm not sure if this is the best approach but it's what came to mind.

```
str.split("IP":\s")
```

Comment: I updated the question with a more specific scenario. Meanwhile +1 for this alternative.

Comment: I was thinking along those same lines, but could that be included as part of `sep=`?  That is, tell `read_csv` that `IP:` is a delimiter along with whitespace.  I don't quite know how to do that syntax though.

Comment: It would be something along the lines of  print(str, sep="IP:\s") for the string str. The \s is for any white space in python.

Comment: It's not quite that easy though, what you are doing will treat `I`, `P`, and `:` as individual delimiters.  We only want `IP:` to be a delimiter as a group. I'm not sure how to do that, or even sure that is is possible to be honest.